# How to add style to wordpress body to disable scroll on click of a specific button?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

how do i add overflow="hidden" style to wordpress body tag on click of a specific button like class="openbtn"

My html code:

```
<div class="filterSidebar">
<button class="openbtn dropbtn" style="width:100%;" onclick="openNav()">Filtra per</button>
<button class="dropbtn" style="width:100%;">Ordina per</button>
```

Comment: have you tried anything yet?  if yes what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Just add or remove a class that has overflow: hidden

```js
document.querySelector(".openbtn").addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.classList.toggle("overflow-hidden");
});

function openNav() {}
```

```css
.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 4000px;
}

.filterSidebar {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="filterSidebar">
  <button class="openbtn dropbtn" style="width:100%;" onclick="openNav()">Filtra per</button>
  <button class="dropbtn" style="width:100%;">Ordina per</button>

</div>
```